# How to output the real time a command takes (and nothing else)?

Tags: unix

How can I output the real time a command takes (and nothing else)?

Example:

This won't work:

```
$ time -p sleep 2 | grep real
real 2.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

I want something like:

```
$ print-real-time sleep 2
2.00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [capture the output of `time`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) first. Then you can process it.

Comment: Right. The question is how to do that...

Comment: Did you bother read the linked article?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it was a link. Thanks!

Comment: Good solution, note however that the entire world is not running bash...

Answer (score 3):

A non-BASH-specific solution (explicitly use `/usr/bin/time` so it's not the pipe-gobbling bash builtin) --

`/usr/bin/time -p some_command_or_subshell 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print $2}'`

Depending on the delicate nature of whatever you feed this output to you may want to redirect the output of your subject command to /dev/null...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky solution using `cut` to split the fields.

```
time -p sleep 2 | grep real | cut -f2 -d' '
```

You can also use `awk`:

```
time -p sleep 2 | grep real | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Does that actually work on your system? On mine, it doesn't give the desired output "2.00".

Comment: It works on mine; but it probably also depends on what `time` command you're running.  It sounds like bash behaves differently with this--zsh gives you the output on stdout normally.

Comment: @Redmumba this is the principle danger of using shell builtins - they may not work the same way for everyone, and in your case they don't conform to the POSIX standard ( `time` is *supposed* to report its output to `stderr`, not `stdout` ; cf. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html  )

Comment: Tres bizarre!  I guess you learn something new everyday.